# log4j conflicts with netty

Tags: log4j, netty

Just installed log4j and got it working pretty well, but I noticed because netty also uses log4j, im getting all the log messages from netty too.  Is there any way I can configure log4j to ignore netty?

also as a side note if theres any way I can configure log4j so I don't have to type

```
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Yourclass.class);
```

in every class  that be great to know too

Answer (score 0):

You can change the log level for `io.netty` to `WARN` or `ERROR`. If you are not familiar with log4j configuration, please read [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) and [this](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat).